# gcc gives me maybe-uninitialized warning when passing void * to a function accepting const void *

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

This code:

```
class X {
};

void f(const void *) {
}

int main() {
    X a;
    void *p = &a;
    f(p);
}
```

compiled with `g++ -Wall test.cpp` issues warning

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:10:6: warning: ‘p’ may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   10 |     f(p);
      |     ~^~~
test.cpp:4:6: note: by argument 1 of type ‘const void*’ to ‘void f(const void*)’ declared here
    4 | void f(const void *) {
      |      ^
test.cpp:8:7: note: ‘a’ declared here
    8 |     X a;
      |       ^
```

However when optimizations are enabled (with `-O1`, `-O2`, or `-O3`) the warning disappears.

Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: When optimization is turned on, all your empty classes and functions without statements are optimized out. Thus, no warnings.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? It doesn't happen with [GCC 4.1.2](https://godbolt.org/z/6Eq68oj3f). (If you want to see the version, just run `g++ -v` in the command line.)

Comment: @Ruks gcc 11.1. Seems that it doesn't happen with 10.3 either.

Comment: @vbstb It seems [there are already a lot of bug reports on false "*-Wmaybe-uninitialized*" warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=maybe%20uninitialized) just like yours. You *could* try filing up a bug report there.

Comment: @Ruks Got it. Thanks.